# when i enter the flutter command in prompt it closes instantly

Tags: flutter

[Flutter - running command "flutter _____" instantly closes terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131473/flutter-running-command-flutter-instantly-closes-terminal#new-answer)

set the path variable as mentioned in the above link

upgraded powershell version from v5.1 to 7

but still my command prompt closes instantly

Comment: do you have vscode? if so, what happens if you run `flutter ____` command from its terminal?

Comment: Deleted the downloaded version from site and then clone it from github and run the command using vs code , its working fine now , Thanks for ur help @pskink

Comment: Could you please elaborate the steps @karthickrathinam