# I was facing error when running dart command on cmd terminal

Tags: dart

whenever I am running dart command my cmd shutdowns

I just run a command: `dart -v` and I was expecting that new version of dart should be printed but the terminal shutsdown or when I am running commands related to dart to configure flutterfire in my pc, commands like : `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

Comment: This could be a missing env variable. Did you try any of the following [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131473/flutter-running-command-flutter-instantly-closes-terminal)?